# Zend OpenID for Google Profile as OpenID

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

I'm using PHP, Zend OpenID, specifically this https://github.com/marcinwol/zfopenid so it works for Google and Yahoo, Facebook, etc...

but it doesn't work for Google Profiles, https://profiles.google.com/{name}

in this example it doesn't work too http://www.mwol.born2die.eu/zfopenid/public/user/login

how to make this work, what's different in https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

first thing I found is that there's no XRDS...

Comment: Works for me at http://www.mwol.born2die.eu/zfopenid/public/user/login

Comment: did you tried login with google profile? for me when I input my Google Profile username I get `Redirection failed`

Comment: yes, it worked correctly with my google profile

Comment: http://i23.fastpic.ru/big/2011/0617/5b/3fa88195f75e85e3d1e4d4f346e93e5b.png

Comment: I tried my named openid  `https://profiles.google.com/davispuh` (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) for stackoverflow it works...